# Is there a job scheduler library for node.js?

Tags: scheduling, node.js

Is there some cron like library that would let me schedule some function to be ran at certain time (15:30 for example, not x hours from now etc)? If there isn't this kind of library how this should be implemented? Should I just set callback to be called every second and check the time and start jobs scheduled for the time or what?

Comment: node-cron seems to be a very good option

Comment: var schedule = require('node-schedule'); is the best things. cheers!!!

Answer (score 125, accepted):

[node-cron](http://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) does just what I described

Comment: do you write the cronjob declarations in app.js/scripts.js?

Comment: does **node-cron** allow you to edit system cron jobs from node.js?  
Is it dependent on the node process running? or will it allow you to run programs even after your main process terminates?

Comment: @Ajar no, after termination of nodejs process, all jobs will be lost. There is no cron table shipped with node-cron

Comment: @ArVan I know this is a couple years later but did you find that app.js/scripts.js was the best place to declare your cronjobs?

Comment: I guess so @ChrisC. If I'm not using any framework, I declare crons in `app.js`. In `sails.js` I do it in `bootstrap`

Comment: @ArVan Thanks, I actually ended up separating it into it's own cron.js file to try to keep it as modular as possible. I will have a lot going on in there so probably best not to polute my app.js in this particular instance.

Comment: @arVan if you're interested, I actually started working on `agenda` to add Waterline support here: https://github.com/mikermcneil/agenda  (literally just started though- should have some usable progress by next week)

Comment: Some of the more popular packages compared:   https://npmcompare.com/compare/agenda,cron,later,node-runnr,node-schedule

Comment: I faced issue with node-cron that it calls twice. I couldn't get rid of it.

Answer (score 45):

[node-schedule](https://github.com/mattpat/node-schedule) A cron-like and not-cron-like job scheduler for Node.

Comment: This manages to avoid the sometimes confusing crontab syntax, and is a little more readable in my opinion.

Comment: like agenda it seams to provide persistence 0.1.13

Comment: node-schedule does not provide persistence.  Per the docs: 
`Note that node-schedule is designed for in-process scheduling, i.e. scheduled jobs will only fire as long as your script is running, and the schedule will disappear when execution completes.`

Answer (score 37):

[agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda) is a Lightweight job scheduling for node. This will help you.

Comment: agenda is based on node-cron with a persisten layer (mongo). so the answer above is better.

Comment: To clarify, as the author of agenda, it is actually not based on node-cron at all...

Comment: I recently wrote a blog comment about an agenda setup. Also it suggests a project structure http://goo.gl/5sCNBM

Comment: The agenda library is the one and only best library as the setup is simple and usage is easy for the user. Kudos @Ryan

Comment: I've found `agenda` to have inconsistent behaviour and would not advise using it.  Check the open issues and PRs to make your own call.

Comment: be aware, agenda is not production ready. It has [memory leak](https://github.com/agenda/agenda/issues/129) issues and check for issues. Still has a lot of bugs. It looks promising when ready.

Comment: regarding "lightweight", according to its dependencies it's not so light... for example: unpacked size of its dependencies - moment-timezone 1.34 MB + moment 4.09 MB + mongodb 1.45 MB ... Although other scheduler packages may have similar deps.

Answer (score 15):

[later.js](http://bunkat.github.io/later/) is a pretty good JavaScript "scheduler" library. Can run on Node.js or in a web browser.

Comment: I tried a few of the suggestions in this thread, but this module I found to be the most *user-friendly* and straight fwd to work with .. thanks!

Comment: For anybody coming around this lib - [here](https://breejs.github.io/later/index.html) is a maintained fork of it.

Answer (score 12):

I am using kue: https://github.com/learnboost/kue . It is pretty nice.

The official features and my comments:

1. delayed jobs.

   - If you want to let the job run at a specific time, calculate the milliseconds between that time and now. Call job.delay(milliseconds)  (The doc says minutes, which is wrong.) Don't forget to add "jobs.promote();" when you init jobs.
2. job event and progress pubsub.

   - I don't understand it.
3. rich integrated UI.

   - Very useful. You can check the job status (done, running, delayed) in integrated UI and don't need to write any code. And you can delete old records in UI.
4. infinite scrolling

   - Sometimes not working. Have to refresh.
5. UI progress indication

   - Good for the time-consuming jobs.
6. job specific logging

   - Because they are delayed jobs, you should log useful info in the job and check later through UI.
7. powered by Redis

   - Very useful. When you restart your node.js app, all job records are still there and the scheduled jobs will execute too!
8. optional retries

   - Nice.
9. full-text search capabilities

   - Good.
10. RESTful JSON API

    - Sound good, but I never use it.

---

Edit:

1. kue is not a cron like library.
2. By default kue does not supports job which runs repeatedly (e.g. every Sunday).

Comment: Kue is a job queue, not a scheduler.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Kue is a job queue. And it is a scheduler too, because it can "let me schedule some function to be ran at certain time".

Comment: I thought Kue jobs can only be delayed, but not scheduled to a certain time.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny You are right. Kue does not provide api to schedule a job to a certain time. But as I mentioned, "If you want to let the job run at a specific time, calculate the milliseconds between that time and now. Call job.delay(milliseconds) (The doc says minutes, which is wrong.)" It's very easy.

Comment: You could try kue-scheduler, which is similar to aganda

Answer (score 10):

You can use **[timexe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timexe)**

It's simple to use, light weight, has no dependencies, has an improved syntax over cron, with a resolution in milliseconds and works in the browser.

Install:

```
npm install timexe
```

Use:

```
var timexe = require('timexe');
var res = timexe("* * * 15 30", function(){ console.log("It's now 3:30 pm"); });
```

(I'm the author)

Comment: may i get some example for this please?

Comment: Please have a look at the examples on github: https://github.com/paragi/timexe

Answer (score 9):

[node-crontab](https://github.com/dachev/node-crontab) allows you to edit system cron jobs from node.js. Using this library will allow you to run programs even after your main process termintates. Disclaimer: I'm the developer.

Comment: so it persists if the node server is reset?

Comment: Found it http://stackoverflow.com/a/5636298/230462

Comment: Yes, jobs are persisted.

Comment: its GPL licensed, so not usable in a commercial project.

Comment: The license is now MIT

Answer (score 3):

I am the auhor of [node-runnr](https://github.com/Saquib764/node-runnr) . It have a very simple approach to create job. Also its very easy and clear to declare time and interval. 
For example, to execute a job at every 10min 20sec,

```
Runnr.addIntervalJob('10:20', function(){...}, 'myjob')
```

To do a job at 10am and 3pm daily,

```
Runnr.addDailyJob(['10:0:0', '15:0:0'], function(){...}, 'myjob')
```

Its that simple.
For further detail: https://github.com/Saquib764/node-runnr

Answer (score 2):

All these answers and noone has pointed to the most popular NPM package .. cron

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Answer (score 1):

Both  [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)  and  [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)  we can use to  implement cron-based schedullers.

**NOTE** : for generating cron expressions , you can use this [cron_maker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This won't be suitable for everyone, but if your application is already setup to take commands via a socket, you can use netcat to issue a commands via cron proper.

```
echo 'mycommand' | nc -U /tmp/myapp.sock
```