# Cronjobs in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

Is there a possibility to periodically call functions at a specific time of the day in node.js? My first implementation was

```
setInterval(functionName(),(24*60*60*1000));
```

This is suboptimal, because it will restart every time I restart node. Are there better possibilities to implement this?

Comment: Use [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron).

Comment: @MathiasBynens How's [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) resistant to restarts? Sorry, for being a necromant, but this Q is still one of the first in Google results. Note that `node-cron` IS NOT based on crontables.

Comment: @meeDamian node-cron mostly runs scripts on intervals, so they will just begin cycling again on restart. There is also an option to run a job once [by date](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron#another-example-with-date), this is a value that will presumably come from a persistent data source.

Answer (score 21):

To guard against restarts you need to create a persistent data stored job.

Something like :

```
Job = {
    _id: Number,
    job: String,
    dueDate: Date,
    completed: Boolean
}
```

Then have some code as follows:

```
var createJob = function(url, date) {
    var j = db.create(Job, function(j) {
         j.job = url;
         j.dueDate = date;
         j.save();
    });
};

var runJob = function(j) {
    var id = j._id;
    setInterval(j.dueDate - Date.now(), function() {
         db.getOne(Job, { _id : id }, function(j) {
             require(j.job);
             j.finished = true;
             j.save();  
         });
    });
    j = null;
};
```

On start up you just have to do something like :

```
db.get(Job, { finished: false }, function(jobs) {
    jobs.forEach(runJob);
});
```

Replace the generic `db` with MongoDB, CouchDB, Redis, etc.

Comment: Suppose there are multiple cron jobs are running, is there any way just simply kill one of them? Because I encountered a scenario I needed to kill one job and did some other maintenance but I still wanted other jobs running. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but in addition to the accepted answer a library  with examples is worth mentioning.

[cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) is a lightweight package which runs the specified function at given interval, using only system's time and no db persistence.

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const jobFiveMinutes = require("./job.five-minutes");
const jobMondayMorning = require("./job.monday-morning");

var jobs = [
    new CronJob({
        cronTime: "00 */5 * * * *", //every five minutes
        onTick: function() {
            jobFiveMinutes();
        },
        start: false, //don't start immediately
        timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
    }),
    new CronJob({
        cronTime: "00 00 9 * * 1", //9 am Monday morning
        onTick: function() {
            jobMondayMorning();
        },
        start: false,
        timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
    }),
];

jobs.forEach(function(job) {
    job.start(); //start the jobs
});
```

Above, we required two files and call them inside of two cronjobs, set at different intervals. The files simply export the functions:

```
//job.five-minutes.js
module.exports = function(){
    console.log("runs every five minutes")
};

//job.monday-morning.js
module.exports = function(){
    console.log("runs every monday morning at 9 am, Los Angeles time")
};
```

Whether you run it locally or on remote server in any region, it will run according to the passed timezone (which is optional though, and does not matter in case of minutes).

Also, restarting the server/script will have no affect on its working as it's synced with system time. A `"00 */5 * * * *"` job will run on each multiple of 5 i.e. 5, 10, 15, 20 and so on. So, even if you restart the script at 24, it will run at 25 not 29.

Lastly, the package has extended the cron syntax to include seconds on the left most. Therefore, you can even tell at what exact second of the minute you want to run the job.