# Push notification at specific time

Tags: php, node.js, push-notification, pusher

I am trying to push few notifications for scheduled todos, for example if i set a task to be run at 2014-12-12 08:15:00, it can push notification at that exact time. I have tried pusher...

```
require('Pusher.php');

$pusher = new Pusher($key, $secret, $app_id);
$pusher->trigger('todo-channel', 'task-event', array('message' => 'hey, you have a task') );
```

How to trigger this task at specific time, i have tried google and search on stackoverflow but couldn't find any better solution.

I can even use `node.js` if you can provide an example, please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is schedule a task or job. This is pretty common practice so there are a number of solutions for this.

Since you've tagged this with `php` take a look at the SO question: [What is the best method for scheduled tasks in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190561/what-is-the-best-method-for-scheduled-tasks-in-php)

A search specifically for Node turns up:

- [Is there a job scheduler library for node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785736/is-there-a-job-scheduler-library-for-node-js)
- [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)
- [agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda) - [blog post](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/npmawesome-agenda/)
- [How a simple Node.js project turned into Iron Scheduler](http://blog.iron.io/2013/12/how-small-nodejs-project-turned-into.html)