# Trigger an URL at a specific time (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

Any ideas on how to reliably trigger an URL (web service) at a specific time? With the precision in seconds? For example, the script will be set so that it will be able to trigger a web service at 2015-05-27 12:34:55. In my scenario, the user will be able to select at what time, down to seconds a trade should execute. The web service must be then triggered at a specific time

- AWS Lambda is not able to run at specific times.
- Cron jobs won't work as it does not run every second
- An SQS might work but coding it up to be reliable could be hard.

Thanks!

Comment: For down to the second timing you will need something that is already running.  Perhaps a Node.js server?  Here are some ideas to a similar question about scheduling in Node.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785736/is-there-a-job-scheduler-library-for-node-js

Comment: Be careful, as http usually does not ensure that requests are processed in the same second they are received. Even if you get the system to work at the exact second, network conditions can create delays and you won't get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

"at" command does what you need: https://calomel.org/cron_at.html

*An addtitional tool one can use is called "at" and is used to execute a job only once. "at" is very useful, for example if you want run a backup job starting at 8pm and you expect to be leaving at 5:30pm.*