# Execute different nodejs scripts at a given time

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for a good solution on fire different javascript files with nodejs at a given time on a Server running on Ubuntu.

I have about 10 different scripts and each should be fired 15 times a day! My first approach was to use [at](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man1/at.1.html) but this gets really messy with that much events.

Now I thought about using [Node-Schedule](https://github.com/tejasmanohar/node-schedule) what some of you guys [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785736/is-there-a-job-scheduler-library-for-node-js) on SO suggested but I'm not sure if that's the best solution for my task ...

If Node-Schedule should still be the best approach - what structure would you use?

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var d1 = new Date(2015, 10, 20, 18, 55, 0);
var d2 = new Date(2015, 10, 20, 18, 58, 0);

var xd1 = schedule.scheduleJob(d1, function(){
    test.js;
});

var xd2 = schedule.scheduleJob(d2, function(){
    test.js;
});
```

Doesn't seems that DRY ... ;)

Comment: this is what cron is designed to handle

Comment: i ended up using plain cron which worked perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't create a node program just to schedule another node program. Use plain cron.

If you can run your job 16 times a day instead of 15 times, it would be every 90 minutes which you can schedule with these two cron expressions:

```
' 0 0/3 * * * node test.js'
'30 1/3 * * * node test.js'
```

If it has to be 15 times, this schedule has pretty good distribution (at most once an hour, at least every other hour, 15 times per day):

```
'0 0/2,1,9,17 * * * node test.js'
```

Any difficulty understanding this schedule, use [this site](http://crontab.guru). If you need your 15 invocations to be spaces equally (every 96 minutes), I'm afraid you'd need to break them into 5 schedules:

```
 0 0,8,16  * * * node test.js
36 1,9,17  * * * node test.js
12 3,11,19 * * * node test.js
48 4,12,20 * * * node test.js
24 6,14,22 * * * node test.js
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run your scripts on a daily basis, this date based scheduling is not the best solution. The cron style scheduling is a better fit.

For example

```
var xd1 = schedule.scheduleJob('0 * * * *', function(){
    test.js;
});
```

will run your function every hour (0:00, 1:00, 2:00 and so on = 24 times a day).

And

```
var xd1 = schedule.scheduleJob('0 */2 * * *', function(){
    test.js;
});
```

will run your function every two hours (0:00, 2:00, 4:00 and so on = 12 times a day).

Is the 15 times a day a hard requirement? You can't define this kind of interval very easy with the cron syntax, without splitting it up into different cronjobs (= define more job with the same function call).

This example would run 15 times a day, but it is not balanced throughout the day:

```
var xd1 = schedule.scheduleJob('*/25 */5 * * *', function(){
    test.js;
});
```